# Run new Liquibase instance on existing databasechangelog db

Tags: liquibase

I dont have much hands on liquibase. I came into one scenario in my recent project, where we do need to develop a separate module for our project which is responsible for its own database tables creation and updating tables using Liquibase.

But the problem over here is, we have to make use of existing schema which is already managing using Liquibase. So it already has DATABASECHANGELOG table.

So when i try to create new tables from my new module, is it going to work inorder to manage them with new Liquibase changeLog files.

All i want to understand is, is it ok to run new liquibase things on existing DATABASECHANGELOG table.

If runs what will happen.I have so much confusion on this, Can somebody explain it elaborately.

Need timely help...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, the first thing Liquibase does when you run a changelog is to check for the two tables it provides. If they don't exist, it creates them. If they do, it uses them.

So you shouldn't have any problems unless your new changesets try do something they shouldn't, like create a table that already exists in the schema.

I would try to arrange things so that your new changesets and existing ones know about each other, though. Where by "know about each other" I mean, "exist in the same codebase".

Comment: Thanks for your reply Martin McCallion. I tried by running change sets on existing db schema and it is working smoothly. How ever i should not add them into existing code base as my module runs as a separate instance so not required to add them to existing codebase.